# DateTimePicker from React Material-UI does not show the timezone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, timezone, datetimepicker

I've been using the **DateTimePicker** from **MUI React library** for the last 2 years. Today I decided to upgrade all the dependencies of the project I work with, and I noticed the **DateTimePicker** is not working anymore. Searching for the documentation, it came up they changed a few properties of this component and, among these, there is the `value` property. As they say here https://mui.com/x/migration/migration-pickers-v5/#update-the-format-of-the-value-prop :

> Previously, it was possible to provide any format that your date
> management library was able to parse. For instance, you could pass
> value={new Date()} when using AdapterDayjs. This behavior brought a
> lot of confusion.
>
> In v6, the format expected by the value prop is the same as for any
> other prop holding a date

Now the property needs a `Date` object. In the previous version I was able to show the date and time with the timezone in **GMT** because I could pass a string instead of a `Date`, but now I'm not able to manage this anymore. Here is my piece of code:

```
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { DateTimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers'
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns'

//some code

<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns} >
    <DateTimePicker
        //other properties
        value={myValue}
        format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss xxx'            
    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Suppose `myValue="2023-05-04T14:26:36.118+02:00"` (value coming from the DB), I want the **DateTimePicker** to render `2023-05-04 14:26:36 GMT+2`. My best try is `2023-05-04 14:26:36 xxx`, but without any information about the timezone (which is mandatory to have in my case). As far I understand, it is impossible to show the timezone because the `format` property is built on the `views` property, which is an object that can have inside keys and values relative to *year, month, day, hour, minutes and second* (with no timezone at all). Am I correct? Is there a way to show the timezone inside the **DateTimePicker** component? Thanks!

Comment: why not passing this: new Date("2023-05-04T14:26:36.118+02:00")?

Comment: Thanks Raphael for the comment. That was one of my tries but the timezone was still not present